# Solving a linear system with large number of equations

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve a system of linear equations having 16 equations and 16 variables. These 16 equations are as below :

eqn1 :

```
 (-2 (p2 (-2 H0  U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 + ((-2 M S0 - S1) U1)/r)) ) l0 + (2 - ( p2 (-H0  U1 - (H1 U1)/r) + p1 p2 ((-B0 - S0) U1 + ((-B1 - S1) U1)/r))) l1 + (-2 ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2)) l2 + (2 a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2)) -2 ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a (H0 + J0) U1))/r^2)) l3 == p2 (2 H0 U1 + (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + p1 p2 (S0 U1 - ((-2 M S0 - S1) U1)/r)
```

eqn 2:

```
((-1 + 2 M/r) (p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 + ((-2 M S0 - S1) U1)/r)) - 2 + (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/r) + p1 p2 ((-B0 - S0) U1 + ((-B1 - S1) U1)/r))) n0 + (2 (-1 + 2 M/r) + 2 (p2 (-H0 U1 + ((-H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + p1 p2 ((-A0 - 2 B0 - S0) U1 + ((-A1 - 2 B1 + 2 A0 M + 4 B0 M + 2 M S0 - S1) U1)/r)) + (1 - 2 M/r) + (-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r) (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/r) + p1 p2 ((-B0 - S0) U1 + ((-B1 - S1) U1)/r))) n1 + ((-1 + 2 M/r) ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2) + 2 (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2)) n2 + (2 a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (-1/2 - M/r) (-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) + 2 a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (-1/2 - M/r) (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2)) + (a p1/r^2) (1 - 2 M/r) + (-1 + 2 M/r) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a (H0 + J0) U1))/r^2) - (2 a p1/r^2) + 2 (-1/r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]]))) n3 == -((1/4) (1 - 2 M/r)^2 (p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 + ((-2 M S0 - S1) U1)/r)) + p2 (-H0 U1 + ((-H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + p1 p2 ((-A0 - 2 B0 - S0) U1 + ((-A1 - 2 B1 + 2 A0 M + 4 B0 M + 2 M S0 - S1) U1)/r) + (-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r) (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/r) +  p1 p2 ((-B0 - S0) U1 + ((-B1 - S1) U1)/r)))
```

eqn 3:

```
(Sqrt[2] r ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
       r^2) + ((-2 a p1 i r Sin[\[Theta]])/(Sqrt[
          2] r^2)) + (Sqrt[
         2] i r Sin[\[Theta]]) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 \
Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a   (H0 + J0) U1))/
       r^2)) m0 + ((Sqrt[
         2] r) (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
       r^2) + ((-2 a  p1 i r Sin[\[Theta]])/(Sqrt[
          2] r^2)) + (Sqrt[2] i r Sin[\[Theta]]) (-1/
         r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
           a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]]))) m1 + ((Sqrt[2] r) (-((
         J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/
        r^2) + (-Sqrt[2]/
       r)) m2 + ((-2/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/(Sqrt[
           2])) + (Sqrt[2] i r Sin[\[Theta]]) (-((
         J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
        T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
        r^2)) m3 == -((r^2/
       2) (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/
       r^2) + ((-r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/
       2) (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
       T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2))
```

eqn 4:

```
(Sqrt[2] r ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
       r^2) + ((+2 a p1 i r Sin[\[Theta]])/(Sqrt[
          2] r^2)) + (-Sqrt[
          2] i r Sin[\[Theta]]) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 \
Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a  (H0 + J0) U1))/
       r^2)) mbar0 + ((Sqrt[
         2] r) (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
       r^2) + ((2 a p1 i r Sin[\[Theta]])/(Sqrt[
          2] r^2)) + (-Sqrt[2] i r Sin[\[Theta]]) (-1/
         r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
           a  (H0 + J0) U1))) mbar1 + ((Sqrt[2] r) (-((J0 p2 U1)/
         r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/r^2) + (-Sqrt[2]/
       r)) mbar2 + ((2/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (i r \
Sin[\[Theta]]/(Sqrt[2])) + (-Sqrt[2] I r Sin[\[Theta]]) (-((
         J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
        T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
        r^2)) mbar3 == -((r^2/2) (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (
       T0 p1 p2 U1)/r^2) + ((-r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/
       2) (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
       T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2))
```

eqn5:

```
((-1/2) (1 - 
        2 M/r) (p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/
           r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 - ((2 M S0 + S1) U1)/
           r)) + (-1) + (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
          r))) l0 + ((-1 + 
       2 M/r) + (p2 (-H0 U1 - ((H1 - 2 H0 M) U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-(A0 + 2 B0 + S0) U1 - ((A1 + 
             2 B1 - 2 A0 M - 4 B0 M - 2 M S0 + S1) U1)/r)) + (1/
        2) (1 - 2 M/r) + (-1/2) (1 - 
        2 M/r) (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
           r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
           r))) l1 + ((-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r) ((
       Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
       r^2) + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
      r^2)) l2 + (((-1)/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (a p1 Sin[\
\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
        M/r) + ((-a p1/r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r)) + ((-1/
         2) (1 - 2 M/r) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
           a  (H0 + J0) U1))/r^2)) + (-1/
        r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
          a  (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) + (-a \[Epsilon]/
        r^2)) l3 + ((-1) (p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 - ((2 M S0 + S1) U1)/
          r))) n0 + ((-1) (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
          r))) n1 + ((-1) ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
      r^2)) n2 + ((-1/
         r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + ((-((
          J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
          r^2)) (a  p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 p1) + (a \
p1/
          r^2) + (-1) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
            a (H0 + J0) U1))/r^2))) n3 == ((1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) (\[Zeta] (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/
         r) + \[Epsilon] \[Zeta] (-S0 U1 + ((-2 M S0 - S1) U1)/
         r)) + ((-1) (\[Zeta] (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
          r) + \[Epsilon] \[Zeta] ((-B0 - S0) U1 + ((-B1 - S1) U1)/
          r))))
```

eqn 6 :

```
(-a p1/r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) (mbar0) + ((r/Sqrt[2]) ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
       r^2)) (mbar0) + (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a (H0 + J0) U1))/
     r^2) (mbar0) + (-a p1/r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) mbar1 + (r/
     Sqrt[2]) (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
     r^2) (mbar1) + (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) (-1/
      r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
       a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (mbar1) + ((-1/r^2) (r/
       Sqrt[2])) mbar2 + (r/
     Sqrt[2]) (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/
      r^2) (mbar2) + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
        Sqrt[2])) mbar3 + (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
        r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
      r^2) (mbar3) + ((-a p1/r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
        Sqrt[2])) m0 + (r/Sqrt[2]) ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
     r^2) (m0) + (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a p1 (H0 + J0) U1))/
     r^2) (m0) + (((-a p1/r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]))) m1 + (r/
     Sqrt[2]) (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
     r^2) (m1) + (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) (-1/
      r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
       a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (m1) + (((-1/r^2) (r/
        Sqrt[2]))) m2 + (r/
     Sqrt[2]) (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/
      r^2) (m2) + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
        Sqrt[2])) m3 + (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
        r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
      r^2) (m3) == -((r^2/
       2) (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/
        r^2) + (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
        Sqrt[2]) (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
          r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2))
```

eqn7:

```
((-1) (p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 - ((2 M S0 + S1) U1)/
          r))) m0 + 
  m1 + ((-1) (p2(-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
          r))) m1 + (-1/r^2) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) l2 + (a p1/r^2) m3 + (-a p1/
      r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) l0 + (-a p1/
      r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) l1 + (-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (a  p1 Sin[\
\[Theta]]^2) m3 + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) l3 + (-1) ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (m2) + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[
      2]) l0 + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[2]) l1 + (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (
     T0 p1 p2 U1)/r^2) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) l2 + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (-1) (m3) + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) l0 + (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) (-1/
      r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a  (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) l1 + (-((
     J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2)) (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (m3) + (-((
      J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
     T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) l3 + (-1) ((
    Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[
      2]) + (-1) ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) + (-((
     J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2)) (a  p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) ((i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2])) == 0
```

eqn 8:

```
((p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/
          r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 - ((2 M S0 + S1) U1)/
          r)) (-1/2) (1 - 
       2 M/r)) m0 + (-1) m0 + (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
        r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
        r)) m0 + (1/2) (1 - 2 M/r) m1 + (-1/2) (1 - 
     2 M/r) (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
        r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
        r)) m1 + (-1 + 
     2 M/r) m1 + (p2 (-H0 U1 - ((H1 - 2 H0 M) U1)/
        r) + p1 p2 (-(A0 + 2 B0 + S0) U1 - ((A1 + 2 B1 - 
           2 A0 M - 4 B0 M - 2 M S0 + S1) U1)/r)) m1 + (-1/r^2) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) n2 + (-a p1/r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
     2 M/r) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) + ((-a p1/r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
       2 M/r)) m3 + (-a p1/r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) n0 + (-a p1/r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) + (-a p1/r^2) m3 + (-a p1/
      r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) (m3) + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (a p1 Sin[\
\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
     M/r) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) + (((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (a p1 Sin[\
\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
       M/r)) m3 + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) m3 + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r) (r/Sqrt[2]) + ((
    Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r) m2 + ((
    Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[
      2]) n0 + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[
      2]) + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) m2 + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[2]) n1 + (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (
     T0 p1 p2 U1)/r^2) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) n2 + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a  (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
     2 M/r) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a  (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
     2 M/r) m3 + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a  (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) n0 + (-1/
      r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) + (-1/
      r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) m3 + (-1/
      r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) n1 + (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2)) (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
     M/r) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) + (-((
     J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2)) (a p1  Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
     M/r) m3 + (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
     T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2) (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) n3 == 0
```

eqn 9:

```
(p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/
        r) + p1 p2 (-S0 U1 - ((2 M S0 + S1) U1)/
        r)) (-1) mbar0 + 
  mbar1 + (-1) (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/
        r) + p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/
        r)) mbar1 + (-1/r^2) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) l2 + (a p1/r^2) mbar3 + (-a p1/
      r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) l0 + (-a p1/
      r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) l1 + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (a p1 Sin[\
\[Theta]]^2) mbar3 + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) l3 + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (-1) (mbar2) + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[
      2]) l0 + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (r/Sqrt[2]) l1 + (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (
     T0 p1 p2 U1)/r^2) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) l2 + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (-1) (mbar3) + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) l0 + (-1/
      r^2 \[Epsilon] \[Zeta] Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (-I r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) l1 + (-((J0 \[Zeta] Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2)) (a \[Epsilon] Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (mbar3) + (-((
      J0 \[Zeta] Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/r^2) - (
     T0 \[Epsilon] \[Zeta] Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2) (-I r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) l3 + ((
    Q0 \[Epsilon] \[Zeta] Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
    r^2) (-1) (r/
     Sqrt[2]) + ((\[Epsilon] \[Zeta] (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - 
       a (H0 + J0) U1))/
    r^2) (-1) (-I r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) + (-((
     J0 \[Zeta] Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
     r^2)) (a \[Epsilon] Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-I r Sin[\[Theta]]/
      Sqrt[2]) == 0
```

eqn 10 :

```
 (p2 (-2 H0 U1 - (2 (H1 + 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + 
      p1 p2 (-S0 U1 - ((2 M S0 + S1) U1)/r)) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) mbar0 + (-1) mbar0 + (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/r) + 
      p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/r)) mbar0 + (1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) mbar1 + (p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/r) + 
      p1 p2 (-(B0 + S0) U1 - ((B1 + S1) U1)/r)) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) mbar1 + (-1 + 
      2 M/r) mbar1 + (p2 (-H0 U1 - ((H1 - 2 H0 M) U1)/r) + 
      p1 p2 (-(A0 + 2 B0 + 
             S0) U1 - ((A1 + 2 B1 - 2 A0 M - 4 B0 M - 2 M S0 + 
              S1) U1)/r)) mbar1 + (-1/r^2) (r/
      Sqrt[2]) n2 + (-a p1/r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) + (-a p1/r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) mbar3 + (-a p1/r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) n0 + (-a p1/r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) + (-a p1/r^2) mbar3 + (-a p1/r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) n1 + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (a p1 \
Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
      M/r) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) \
(-1/2 - M/r) mbar3 + ((-1/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) mbar3 + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) (r/Sqrt[2]) + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2) (-1/
      2) (1 - 2 M/r) mbar2 + ((Q0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2) (r/
      Sqrt[2]) n0 + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2) (r/
      Sqrt[2]) + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/
      r^2) mbar2 + (((Q0 + R0) p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r^2) (r/
      Sqrt[2]) n1 + (-((J0 p2 U1)/r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 U1)/r^2) (r/
      Sqrt[2]) n2 + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a (H0 + J0) U1))/
      r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a (H0 + J0) U1))/
      r^2) (-1/2) (1 - 
      2 M/r) mbar3 + ((p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U2 - a (H0 + J0) U1))/
      r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) n0 + (-1/
       r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) + (-1/
       r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) mbar3 + (-1/
       r^2 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]] ((Q0 + R0) U2 + 
        a (H0 + J0) U1 Sin[\[Theta]])) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) n1 + (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
        r^2)) (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
      M/r) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) + (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
        r^2)) (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
      M/r) mbar3 + (-((J0 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
         r^2) - (T0 p1 p2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2 U1)/
       r^2) (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) n3 == 0
```

eqn 11 :

```
 -n1 + 
   l0 + ((-1/2) (1 - 2 M/r)) l1 == (p1 p2 (B0 U1 + (B1 U1)/r) + 
    p2 (-H0 U1 - (H1 U1)/r))
```

eqn 12 :

```
(-r/Sqrt[2]) m0 + (-r/Sqrt[2]) mbar0 - 
   n2 + ((-1/2) (1 - 
        2 M/r)) l2 == (p1 p2 (-R0 Csc[\[Theta]] U3 - (R1 \
Csc[\[Theta]] U3)/r))
```

eqn 13:

```
 -n3 + (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - M/r) l0 + (-1/2) (1 - 
       2 M/r) l3 + (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) n0 - (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
        Sqrt[2]) m0 - (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
        Sqrt[2]) m0 == (p1 p2 (R0 U2 Sin[\[Theta]] + (R1 U2 Sin[\
\[Theta]])/r)))
```

eqn 14:

```
l2 - (r/Sqrt[2]) m1 - (r/
      Sqrt[2]) mbar1 == (p1 p2 (-Q0 Csc[\[Theta]] U3 - (Q1 Csc[\
\[Theta]] U3)/r))
```

eqn 15:

```
 (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - M/r) l1 + 
   l3 + (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) n1 - (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) m1 - (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) mbar1 == (p1 (a Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + 
      p2 (Q0 U2 Sin[\[Theta]] + (Q1 U2 Sin[\[Theta]])/r)))
```

eqn 16:

```
(a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-1/2 - 
      M/r) l2 + (a p1 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) n2 - (r/
      Sqrt[2]) mbar3 - (-i r Sin[\[Theta]]/
       Sqrt[2]) m2 - (i r Sin[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[2]) mbar2 - (r/
      Sqrt[2]) mbar3 == 0
```

Here p1 and p2 denote the order of the given term. Forex a sin[\theta] p1 is a term of order p1. (this is regarding metric perturbation in general relativity - I got these terms from the perturbed metric up to order (p1 + p2 + p1 p2)).

{l1,l2,l3,l4,n1,n2,n3,n4,m1,m2,m3,m4,mbar1,mbar2,mbar3,mbar4} are 16 variables which I want to find out by solving this system of simultaneous equations. {l1,l2,l3,l4,n1,n2,n3,n4} are real.
{m1,m2,m3,m4,mbar1,mbar2,mbar3,mbar4} are complex. mbar1 is a complex conjugate of m1. mbar2 is a complex conjugate of m2 and so for m3 and m4. While writing code, one should tell Mathematica these conditions.

All other quantities like U1, U2, U3, T0, T1, M, a, H0, H1, J0, J1 and all other such are constants.

i is the usual iota that is used to express complex numbers.

I am trying to solve this for more than a month and still couldn't get the answer. I tried solving this using command Solve. It is showing large output and when I select to show all, the system is not responding. What I understand happening is that - it is calculating all powers of r - 1/r, 1/r^2, 1/r^3 ...and all higher orders Mathematica is calculating and hence the output is getting very large.

However, I want answers only up to the order of (1/r) or (1/r^2). I do not want higher-order terms.

I am doing this same problem for more than a month and still couldn't get answer. It will be really helpful if anyone can suggest any code for doing this lengthy problem.

Comment: Maybe try: `NSolve` ?

Comment: In Mathematica, `Sqrt[-1]` is entered as `I` rather than `i`. If `NSolve[{eqns, constraints} // Flatten, vars]` doesn't work, try minimizing the sum of the square errors: `NMinimize[{Total[(#[[1]] - #[[-1]])^2 & /@ eqns], constraints}, vars]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, while solving, I had entered Sqrt[-1] as - esc+i+i+esc. How to give constraints? I am new to programming and do not have that much knowledge. Can you please let me know how should I give constraints here?

Comment: Please provide your equation in form that all equations might be cpoied in one step, thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon NSolve is also not working. Further, I don't want numerical results. For some other simpler problems, I tried NSolve , it gives answer in the form 1.002 x+0.007 y... I do not want answer in this form. I want answer in the form  x+5y(this answer is not for this problem, I am just giving an example)

Comment: Let your equations be `eqn[1]` through `eqn[16]` Then assuming that all constants are real, rewrite the equations using `eqns = ComplexExpand[(eqn /@ Range[16]) /. {mbar1 -> Conjugate[m1], mbar2 -> Conjugate[m2], mbar3 -> Conjugate[m3], mbar4 -> Conjugate[m4]} /. {m1 -> m1r + I*m1i, m2 -> m2r + I*m2i, m3 -> m3r + I*m3i, m4 -> m4r + I*m4i}];` The 16 variables are then `vars = {l1, l2, l3, l4, n1, n2, n3, n4, m1r, m1i, m2r, m2i, m3r, m3i, m4r, m4i};` Then try `sol = Solve[{eqns, Element[Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]], Reals]} // Flatten, vars];`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you so much for the code. From this code you suggested in the above comment, now I have got an idea of how to give constraints and how to deal with equations involving complex entities. But unfortunately sol = Solve[{eqns, Element[Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]], Reals]} // Flatten, vars]; is also not working. For more than 8 hours, it still shows running not giving any output.

Comment: What if any constraints do you know about the parameters/variables? If any are positive, or negative, or …; add these constraints to the system.

Comment: Thank you all. I got the answer. Not for these equations, but I modified my calculations to rewrite these equations in some other form, which I was finally able to solve after two months.